# Cypress get content of several DIVs, and compose one long string

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have some divs that render this way:

```
<div class="customer-data-column">
   <h3>Title:</h3>
   <div>Name Lastname</div>
   <div>123 Address xxx yyy</div>
   <div>Chicago XY 33056</div>
   <div>Country name</div>
</div>
```

This content is generated by:

```
{customerData.replaceAll("/r", "").split("\n").map(item => <div key={item}>{item}</div>)}
```

This data is coming from redux.
In console log (from redux data) the address appears this way:

```
Name Lastname\n123 Address xxx yyy\nChicago XY 33056\nCountry name
```

I want to check in Cypress if this address is correct, the same that is in redux.
I need some way that merges the content of the divs into one string, and adds the `\n` between each div.

I thought I could start this way:

```
  cy.get('.customer-data-column').should($title => {
      const store = Cypress.store.getState();
  
  const reduxPath = store.customerData;
  
  expect("not sure what to put here... how to merge").to.equals(reduxPath)
```

Can anyone please help?

===
**EDIT**

I made it almost work this way:
I added a class to the inner divs, so they render this way:

```
<div class="customer-data-column">
   <h3>Title:</h3>
   <div class="address-row">Name Lastname</div>
   <div class="address-row">123 Address xxx yyy</div>
   <div class="address-row">Chicago XY 33056</div>
   <div class="address-row">Country name</div>
</div>
```

And the test:

```
  cy.get('.address-row').then($divList => {
    const textArray = Cypress.$.makeArray($divList).map(el => el.innerText)
    const actual = textArray.join(textArray, '\n') // use join to array of strings into single string
    expect(actual).to.eql(billToAddress)
  })
```

However it still fails with such message:

> assert expected Name LastnameName Lastname,23 Address xxx yyy,Chicago
> XY 33056,Country name23 Address xxx yyyName Lastname,23 Address xxx
> yyy,Chicago XY 33056,Country name7th FloorName Lastname,23 Address xxx
> yyy,Chicago XY 33056,Country nameBrooklyn NY 11210Name Lastname,23
> Address xxx yyy,Chicago XY 33056,Country nameCountry name to deeply
> equal Name Lastname\n23 Address xxx yyy\n7th Floor\nBrooklyn NY
> 11210\nCountry name

Edit 2:
The solution that I found and works is this one:

```
.then(users => {
  const billToAddress = users.response.body.filter(el => el.orderNumber === '3-331877')[0]
    .billTo

  cy.get('.address-row').each((item, index) => {
    cy.log(cy.wrap(item).should('contain.text', billToAddress.split('\n')[index]))
  })
})
```

Of course if somebody has a better way for achieving this test, I am open to learn more and code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an array of the store data, an `.each()` loop can compare them.

```js
const store = Cypress.store.getState()
const reduxData = store.customerData    // expect 'Name Lastname\n123 Address xxx yyy\nChicago XY 33056\nCountry name'
const reduxDataArray = reduxData.split('\n')

cy.contains('.customer-data-column', 'Title:')
  .find('div')                         // only divs inside '.customer-data-column'
  .each(($div, index) => {
    expect($div.text()).to.eq(reduxDataArray[index])
  })
```

From other comment, it looks like `cy.get('.custom-data-column')` isn't strong enough to isolate this HTML you need to work on.

Perhaps `cy.contains('.customer-data-column', 'Title:')` is better.

---

**All text at once**

In this particular case you can test all text at once by globally removing `\n`

```js
const store = Cypress.store.getState()
const reduxData = store.customerData    // expect 'Name Lastname\n123 Address xxx yyy\nChicago XY 33056\nCountry name'
const reduxAllTexts = reduxData.replace(/\n/g, '')

cy.contains('.customer-data-column', 'Title:')
  .find('div')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('eq', reduxAllTexts)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Cypress function yields multiple elements, we can join the text of those elements to create your string.

```js
cy.get('.custom-data-column').find('div').then(($divList) => {
  const store = Cypress.store.getState();
  const reduxPath = store.customerData;
  const textArray = $divList.map((x) => x.text()); // get the text values as an array
  const actual = textArray.join(textArray, '\n'); // use join to array of strings into single string
  expect(actual).to.eql(reduxPath);
});
```

Comment: It gives: `> 192 |         const textArray = $divList.map(x => x.text()) // get the text values as an array` The arrow ^ is below the "T" of `x.text()`. The output printed to console says `TypeError: x.text is not a function at HTMLDivElement.eval`

Comment: if I `cy.log($divList)` Iget `log[ <div>, 14 more... ]` .... if I open `prevObject` I see 3 times `div.column.bill-to-column`. Each of them has `childNodes` and `children` with `h3` and `div`

Comment: What I can add. In cypress logs I see `- find div`. And after a red line `thenfunction(){}`. The `- find div` row has  the "eye" icon. One or more elements are not visible. However if I put cursor hover it, I see the address is well visible in Cypress browser and gets highlighted.

Comment: Are there multiple elements with a `custom-data-column` class?

Comment: only one. The 14 more divs (when I check it) are the same. It's like they are repeating the same. The same address line is repeating about 3-4 times. However in the rendering they appear of course only once, like a normal address.

Comment: I added an edit to the original question. I tried a different way to compare... but as you can see those dives are seen by Cypress somehow as duplicated...